SpringBoot 3.2 RestClient testing with Mockk treating requests with different body are the same
I'm using SpringBoot 3.2 with the new introduced RestClient. I have a logic that calling to the same API 2 times with different body. In the test, I mock the RestClient requests and test each RestClient request with different request body is invoked exactly 1. (This was fine using RestTemplate)
@Test
fun `test API call 2 times`() {
  every {
    restClient
            .post()
            .uri(URL)
            .headers(any())
            .body(APIRequest(foo))
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(String::class.java)
    } returns ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK)
  }
  every {
    restClient
            .post()
            .uri(URL)
            .headers(any())
            .body(APIRequest(bar))
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(String::class.java)
    } returns ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK)
  }
  
  service.process()

  verify(exactly = 1) {
    restClient
            .post()
            .uri(URL)
            .headers(any())
            .body(APIRequest(foo))
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(String::class.java)
  }
  verify(exactly = 1) {
    restClient
            .post()
            .uri(URL)
            .headers(any())
            .body(APIRequest(bar))
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(String::class.java)
  }
}

But the test failed, it recognized 2 RestClient requests are the same:
java.lang.AssertionError: Verification failed: call 1 of 6: RestClient(restClient#2).post()). 2 matching calls found, but needs at least 1 and at most 1 calls
Calls:
1) RestClient(restClient#2).post()
2) RestClient(restClient#2).post()

We can use @RestClientTest but it just mock the endpoint response.
So how can I test the RestClient was actually invoked with correct request body?

The verification does not work the way you intend it to.
you are expecting that the whole chained command is called exactly as you want it. However, what the verification actually does, is that it checks first if restClient.post() is called once - and it's not. it's called twice. The difference would then only manifest later down the chain, which is nothing that mockk cares for at this point.
Presumably in your old code, the verification looked something like this: restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, unmarshallingType) - which is why it worked because there was no chaining - postForObject was just called once but with different parameters
I don't know if Mockk has a feature to validate such chained calls but I can imagine that's not the case.
In any case, with the new API of restClient your test has become really unstable for another reason to: you are mocking exactly this chain:
every {
    restClient
            .post()
            .uri(URL)
            .headers(any())
            .body(APIRequest(bar))
            .retrieve()
            .toEntity(String::class.java)
    } returns ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK)
  }
  

meaning that this expects that in your production code, you'll have to reproduce the same chain. if you ever change your production code to change the order of parameters in the builder like this (notice that the order of headers and body have changed)
restClient
    .post()
    .uri(URL)
    .body(APIRequest(bar))
    .headers(any())
    .retrieve()
    .toEntity(String::class.java)

the test will fail again, because mockk will not be able to identify that the order of these calls is irrelevant.
Therefore I would suggest, you refactor the code and encapsulate restClient into a class that specifically serves the purpose of what you want your API request to do. That class then should be much easier to mock.

Appreciate your answer. I see, testing chaining like that seems not work. I'm doing a migration from RestTemplate to RestClient, I thought it's a no brainer task, sight. I will look for a better way to write this test. Thanks a lot!
